# Show jquery datepicker with HTML/CSS image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have seen some post about the datepicker but none of these questions could give me the answer to mine.

The deal is that i have used the datepicker function (widget) from jquery which is:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "/debasis/hoofdstuk03/img/calendar.png",
      buttonText: "Open de kalender",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      inline: true,  
      showOtherMonths: true,  
      dayNamesMin: ['Ma', 'Di', 'Wo', 'Do', 'Vr', 'Za','Zo'],  
      monthNames: ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maart', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni',
            'Juli', 'Augustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'],

    });
  });
```

The html that goes with it is:

```
<input type="hidden" id="datepicker">
```

As you can see i have used the button image to show the image and to show the calendar when clicking on the image. Though the problem with this is that i want to style my image (currently it is to big) and i have no clue, since i am quite a nooby in Jquery, how to do this properly. Can i for example style the image without css and just in the function itself? I have read something about .height and .width but i have no clue how to include it so it works. I also tried to do it with html and setting the src and id so i could style it with css/html, and then i try'd to change the function to a 'click on ' function (the id). But this wouldnt do anything (the function didnt work), this is probably because i just inserted the code in a weird/not possible way (since i'm a jquery nooby).

So could anyone point me in the right direction here:)

Thx for the help in advance!

Comment: Why are you using a hidden input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery UI datepicker widget will place the image you choose directly after the input, so you can select with via CSS by using the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) (`+`):

```
#datepicker + img {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9Eacw/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can style the image using CSS. Target the element with:

```
#datepicker img {

  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;

}
```

jQuery will also assign a class to the image `ui-datepicker-trigger` that you could use to target the image with CSS.

Comment: forgot `+` plus sign, see other answer.